# Merge C# collections of a List<T> with a List<IGrouping<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I am trying to merge this two collection into one list but one of the collection is  `List<IGrouping<T>>`. I am trying to merge the `groupedSubscriptions` (which is a `List<IGrouping<int, Subscription>>`) with the `ListOfSubscriptionsSecond` (which is a `List<Subscription>`) to create the `FullListOfSubscriptions` which is, finally, a `List<Subscription>`. See code sample below.

I'm getting a compile time error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
> Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<int, ListObject.Program.Subscription>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ListObject.Program.Subscription>'

Logical example of what I'm trying

```
List<Subscription> FullListOfSubscriptions = new List<Subscription>();

List<Subscription> ListOfSubscriptions = new List<Subscription>();
ListOfSubscriptions.Add(new Subscription() { SubscriptionId = 1, ParentProductId = 4, ChildProductId = 4, ParentProductName = "Product 1", ChildProductName = "Product 1", GroupId = 362 });
ListOfSubscriptions.Add(new Subscription() { SubscriptionId = 2, ParentProductId = 114, ChildProductId = 1, ParentProductName = "Product 2", ChildProductName = "Product 3", GroupId = 1 });
ListOfSubscriptions.Add(new Subscription() { SubscriptionId = 3, ParentProductId = 114, ChildProductId = 2, ParentProductName = "Product 2", ChildProductName = "Product 4", GroupId = 1 });

var groupedSubscriptions = ListOfSubscriptions.GroupBy(u => u.GroupId);
var flattenedSubscriptions = groupedSubscriptions.SelectMany(grp => grp.AsEnumerable()).ToList();

List<Subscription> ListOfSubscriptionsSecond = new List<Subscription>();
ListOfSubscriptionsSecond.Add(new Subscription() { SubscriptionId = 4, ParentProductId = 4, ChildProductId = 4, ParentProductName = "Product 1", ChildProductName = "Product 1", GroupId = 362 });
ListOfSubscriptionsSecond.Add(new Subscription() { SubscriptionId = 5, ParentProductId = 114, ChildProductId = 1, ParentProductName = "Product 2", ChildProductName = "Product 3", GroupId = 1 });
ListOfSubscriptionsSecond.Add(new Subscription() { SubscriptionId = 6, ParentProductId = 114, ChildProductId = 2, ParentProductName = "Product 2", ChildProductName = "Product 4", GroupId = 1 });

//FullListOfSubscriptions = ListOfSubscriptionsSecond.AddRange(groupedSubscriptions);

FullListOfSubscriptions = groupedSubscriptions
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.AsEnumerable())
    .Concat(ListOfSubscriptionsSecond); // <<= I'm getting error here
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Flatten your list of grouping, or somehow resolve the fact that you have groups of items rather than just a flat list of items. Do you know how grouping works in Linq? It's hard to recommend an approach without knowing how you want to fix your group collection.

Comment: I concur with @gunr2171 : it would be helpful to know what exact collections you are trying to merge together. Is it `ListOfSubscriptions` with `ListOfSubscriptionsSecond` ? Or is it `groupedSubscriptions` with  something else ?

Comment: what do you mean by flatten your list of grouping is that making an extra List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on what exactly you want to do. Let's say you have a class like below

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can merge like

```cs
public IEnumerable<Employee> Merge(IEnumerable<Employee> employees,
    IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Employee>> employeesByDept)
{
    // Just merge all employees
    return employeesByDept
        .SelectMany(grp => grp.AsEnumerable()) // flatten
        .Concat(employees); // concat the other
}
```

If you want to merge the whole set as `IGrouping`, there can be many ways of doing that, one of that is just flatten the already grouped one, `concat` the other list and group again.

```cs
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Employee>> MergeGroup(IEnumerable<Employee> employees,
    IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Employee>> employeesByDept)
{
    return  employeesByDept
        .SelectMany(grp => grp.AsEnumerable()) // flatten
        .Concat(employees) // concat the other
        .GroupBy(e => e.Department); // group again
}
```

Few thigs to understand here:

1. [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netcore-3.1) is a high level collections interface, which most of the collections (if not all) implement. These are only meant for iteration i.e. going over the collection & reading data. It does not allow modification of any sort.
2. [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) is a commonly used implementation of `IEnumerable`, which is a concrete class AND also supports modification.
3. A `List<T>` can be assigned to an `IEnumerable<T>`, but not vice-versa. Learn about [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/).
4. And learn about [IGrouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: I have tried your SelectMany idea but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Also the groupedSubscriptions result in two record but when I do SelectMany it is back to the three records?

Comment: That is because, `concat` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, and you are trying to assign it to a `List<T>`

Comment: Do like this: `FullListOfSubscriptions = groupedSubscriptions
                .SelectMany(grp => grp.AsEnumerable())
                .Concat(ListOfSubscriptionsSecond).ToList();`